# Pull a div from one WordPress site into another WordPress site

Tags: php, import

I have 3 separate sites/installs on the same server and they all use the same database:

- xxxx.com/en
- xxxx.com/de
- xxxx.com/es

I want a `<div>` from a specific site in `xxxx.com/en` to appear on the other sites. Let's say I have `<div id="table1">xxxx<div>` on `xxxx.com/en/page1`; I want this to show on `xxxx.com/de/page1`.

I did not think this would be so complicated in WordPress. With plain PHP, it would be just an include, but WordPress is a closed system. So, how can I do this?

Comment: It sounds to me from the comments on answers below like you will want to look into [WordPress Network / Multisite](https://wordpress.org/support/article/create-a-network/) Read the docs thoroughly and plan a way forward. Also I'd suggest editing your question as the above simply suggests front-end sharing of a single div - with no mention of editing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use a translation plugins. one simple and free such as PolyLang would make that much more easy, and you'd be able to use / create different template pages for each language. here is a link to get started: 
https://www.wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/

Answer (score 0):

Sure, this can be done, but requires some work. Here's the approach I would take:

1. In the source install, make a page that has its own template, which includes just the `<div>` you want to pull out (no header, footer, sidebar and so on). In this way you can have the source install assemble the data, just as if it were a regular post. You could even use [`query_vars`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) if the `<div>` you want is dynamic. Basically, you make sure the source install delivers the desired html with a call like this:

   `http://example.com/en/mydivpage?my_var=something`
2. Now you have to pull this html (which is not a full webpage) into the target install. Probably the easiest way would be to use the [jquery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) command.

   `<script>$("#putithere").load("http://example.com/en/mydivpage?my_var=something");</script>
   ...
   <div id="putithere"></div>`
3. Finally, to make this really work, you'll have to solve a security issue. By default browsers won't allow loading html from another domain, unless by iframe. However, you can [allow certain trusted domains to violate this rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work).

I mentioned the `<iframe>` option. Under 1. make sure you include `<head>` and `body` tags. Then under 2. just include the full webpage. The drawback of this approach is that the target's page css won't work inside the frame.

Comment: Hello, Thanx for this approach...but i want this site to be editable in one wordpress installation...i tried a simple html site, i called it page-test.php,  but it does not even show up 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
testsite
 </body>
</html>

Comment: Hello, now i made a new page like test1 and i have this output: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>test</body>
</html>`

now i have to get `test` from that page...how can i do that?

Comment: Follow the link to jquery load in my answer. You can load parts of a page. But the crossdomain scripting rules still apply.

Comment: Now i looked into the jquery doc and saw that you can load an element of the page based on an id, so i have now:

`<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
</head>  
<body><span id="test1">test<span></body>  
</html>  `  
  
and the jquery would be:  
  
`$( "#mysnippet" ).load( "en/test1 #test1" );`  
  
the problem is now, the snippet test is actually a part of another page... but wordpress does not allow inserting code into the editor-page...